# Did the Mesan Alignment plot ever get a conclusion?

Tags: honorverse

The final two books in the separated threads of the *Honorverse* "main" [timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse#Honor_Harrington_series) were *Uncompromising Honor* (2018) and *Shadow of Victory* (2016)

> While *Uncompromising Honor* wrapped up the Manticore-Solarian League conflict into  a reasonably neat little bow, *Shadow of Victory* ended with Mike Henke's tenth fleet arriving at Mesa to witness a self inflicted nuclear holocaust as cover for the top brass of the Mesan Alignement scooting off to parts unknown.

Given the Mesan alignement have been revealed over the last 6-10 books or so as the driving engine of most of the interstellar conflicts, I was surprised to see that this plot point was left so open-ended with little apparent interest in follow up from an in-universe perspective.

Have I missed a release that hasn't made its way to Wikipedia or Goodreads lists?

Comment: I wouldn’t know for sure, but David Weber is getting on in years and has a heart-condition (he got a pacemaker a few years ago). Seems he is mainly concentrating on his collaborations with other authors lately. No news from the Honorverse as far as I know. The Bahzell series is silent too (last volume, Sword of the South, was in 2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Measan Alignment plotline has now been continued in *To End In Fire*. It significantly complicates the questions of what the Alignment actually is, and who is running it and why, in my view. It brings a sub-arc to a conclusion. It does not fully end the question of "What will happen with/to the Alignment". It leaves room for a further book. Whether Weber will write one I have no idea -- I have not seen any announcements from him or anyone even claiming to know.

Answer (score 1):

Mesan Alignment is main story arc of the *Crown of Slaves* series. As Weber put it: "that is the case of tail wagging the dog" (or words to that effect). He was caught off guard by his co-laborers on both this and *Shadow of Saganami* spin-off.

Do not quote me on it, but I believe Weber himself stated that, since they all not only intersect with each other, they were actually sharing the same story arc (amended since CoS) with *Honorverse*, they all are heading into common conclusion.

So, if I remember correctly there is one more book in it for Weber, as somewhat announced with release of *Mission of Honor* (which was supposed to be last in the series, IIRC), but yes, lately the rumors aren't flying.

I also heard that John Ringo wants to continue *Empire of Man* series, but he's running into same issue: David is busy, so there are, apparently, issues.

As for plot left open-ended... Maybe. Or maybe not... David Weber is not the type to be so sloppy.

So... What happened to the *Harvest Joy*???

Comment: Does the Crown of Slaves series go past the point where 10th Fleet arrives at Mesa? I got the impression it was focused on an earlier period before the Alignment's Operation Houdini.

Comment: Doesn't matter. As I mention, all three prongs are now one, single story arc and they are heading into common conclusion. That is why *Uncompromising Honor* and  *Cauldron of Ghosts* contain excerpts - of sorts - from one another. If I remember correctly: all spin-off are currently being merged back into main line and there's one more book to go. That's not to say there won't be continuation to the spin-offs after that, but then again: there's the *Manticore Ascendant* series out there. This looks more promising for continuation at the moment.

Comment: Looking at [Honorverse Fandom](https://honorverse.fandom.com/wiki/Cauldron_of_Ghosts#Plot) plot outline, it seems Cauldron of Ghosts concludes at roughly the same point in the Mesan plot line as Uncompromising Honor. So another book would presumably move both lines forward. It's this next bit that I'm interested in, and from your answer I guess the current status is "not yet written".